# NRF52832 Проблема с видимостью

Tags: микроконтроллеры

Уже как неделю мучаюсь с платой, на борту nrf52835, внешняя антенна. Пытаюсь запустить пример с Установил nrf connect sdk, загружаю примеры разные с работой bluetooth из nrf sdk (через segger ide) и nrf connect sdk, устройство не находится. В моем понимании оба примера должны из коробки работать, но увы. Когда использую nrf connect, в build configuration указывал борду nrf52DK и пытался создать кастомную, но ни то ни то не сработало. Примеры со светодиодами работают нормально. Проекты залил на облако. https://dropmefiles.com/TB9xW